# How do you test your html on mobile?

Tags: html, localhost

I use `Brackets` editor to develop, I can check website on `Chrome` in desktop with :

```
http://127.0.0.1:49371/index.html
```

But it won't load on my iPhone (same wifi)

(I know I can play with the window on chrome, I need actual mobile device)

Couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngrok is good for this, it allows you to publicly share local urls https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to do. One solution that is easy, however, is to code on codepen.io and view your projects in debug view on mobile.

Comment: Ah really? even that they are on the same wifi? can't setup my mac to be the host?

Comment: @Curnelious I use Windows, so I wouldn't know. Codepen has been tried and tested by a lot of people, so I trust it.

Comment: You can set up local tunnels on Mac or PC, generally it's a big pita. Try ngrok like I posted, quick and easy and secure.